# Is it possible to buy a printed copy of an inflight magazine?

Tags: shopping, british-airways

I'm interested specifically in the British Airway's inflight magazine "High Life", for which I couldn't find any printed copies outlet.

Comment: It’s available free online via an app ‘British Airways High Life’

Comment: @Traveller, thanks, but I'm interested specifically in a printed copy. I've edited the title accordingly.

Comment: Have you contacted BA's customer relations department? Since the in-flight magazines are primarily an offshoot of the marketing department, they might be happy to provide you with copies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic as it's not about travel.

Comment: In my experience, the copy on the plane is considered complimentary to take with you, and they have stacks of them in the airport lounge. It shouldn't be too hard to pick one up for free.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to buy the magazine. British Airways do offer an [application](https://itunes.apple.com/dz/app/the-high-life/id1108893870?mt=8) bit it doesn't look like it doesn't look like it's updated regularly.

British Airways also offer an [online version](https://entertainment.ba.com/en/magazine/).

Comment: How do you know for certain that it's not possible to buy printed copies?

Answer (score 1):

You can find [lots of these on Ebay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/British-Airways-Collectable-Airline-Brochures-Inflight-Magazines/108935/bn_7027971058). It may be hard to find a current edition though.

Comment: Thanks, it's a great idea! But as you say, people seem to sell mostly vintage editions.